# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException when wrong password given

Tags: c#, cryptography

The code I have encrypts and decrypts strings for me with help of a password.

When I enter a wrong password I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Here is my code of the crypto class:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

namespace EncryptStringSample
{
public static class StringCipher
{
    // This constant string is used as a "salt" value for the PasswordDeriveBytes     function calls.
    // This size of the IV (in bytes) must = (keysize / 8).  Default keysize is 256, so     the IV must be
    // 32 bytes long.  Using a 16 character string here gives us 32 bytes when converted to a byte array.
    private const string initVector = "tu89geji340t89u2";

    // This constant is used to determine the keysize of the encryption algorithm.
    private const int keysize = 256;

    public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase)
    {
        byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(initVector);
        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
        RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string passPhrase)
    {
        byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector);
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
        RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
        int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
    }
  }
}
```

The error occurs here :

```
int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
```

I call everything here:

```
// encrypting the raw text using PrivateKey
text_encrypted = EncryptStringSample.StringCipher.Encrypt(text_raw, PrivateKey);

// decrypting encrypted message using Partners Private Key
string text_decrypted = EncryptStringSample.StringCipher.Decrypt(decrypt_me, partner_PrivateKey);
```

What causes this exception and how should it be handled?

Comment: Some things that might help you get an answer: Where are you calling your code? Is the error in Encrypt or Decrypt? What parameters are you passing to the methods? When in doubt, you can include the error stack trace. As it is, the information you've given is not enough to find your problem. Also, check out the C# [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement: you should use it for your Streams.

Comment: Hello, I am getting the problem when I decrypt. here is the code for that: string text_decrypted = EncryptStringSample.StringCipher.Decrypt(decrypt_me, partner_PrivateKey);

Comment: and as said I am getting the error when the Private Key is not the same as the entered one when encrypted (code: text_encrypted = EncryptStringSample.StringCipher.Encrypt(text_raw, PrivateKey);)

Comment: A few notes: 1) You can't rely on getting this error. I'd expect no error despite the wrong password in about 1 in 256 tests. 2) Your code sucks. No salt or IV (=> multi-target attacks), incorrect comments (key size and IV size are unrelated and 16 ASCII characters when encoded with UTF-8 produce 16 bytes, not 32), potential truncation of plaintext (`Stream.Read` may return less bytes than requested) and no MAC (=> padding oracles or similar attacks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is to be expected to have CryptographicException when using invalid password.

Your code works fine when providing correct password so just simply catch exception and react properly (display message to end user or something).

Alternatively you can add

```
symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
```

and after decryption you should remove eight `\0` values showing that decryption was successful.